# Switch Statement, it does not work with prompt

Tags: javascript, syntax, switch-statement, prompt

I just learned switch statements. I was practicing it by building something. When i set the value of variable to a number it works but when i asks the user for a number it always **outputs the default statement**.

It works with this code:

```
confirm("You want to learn basic counting?");
var i = 0;
switch (i) {
    case 0:
        console.log(i);
        i++
    case 1:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 2:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 3:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 4:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 5:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 6:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 7:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 8:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 9:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 10:
        console.log(i);
        console.log("Congratulations!");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Buzz, wronghh");
        break;
}
```

But when i asks value from user, it dosen't work. Code below doesn't work:

```
confirm("You want to learn basic counting?");
var i = prompt("Type any number from where you want to start counting[Between 0 and 10]");
switch (i) {
    case 0:
        console.log(i);
        i++
    case 1:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 2:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 3:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 4:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 5:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 6:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 7:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 8:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 9:
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    case 10:
        console.log(i);
        console.log("Congratulations!");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Buzz, wronghh");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to convert the user input from a string to an integer, like so

```
confirm("You want to learn basic counting?");
var i = prompt("Type any number from where you want to start counting[Between 0 and 10]");
i = parseInt(i); // this makes it an integer
switch(i) {
//...
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that prompt answer is always a string.

Answer (score 3):

The [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement performs a [strict comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) between the input expression and case expressions. The output of the following would be:

```
var i = 1;
switch (i) {
    case "1":
        console.log('String 1');
        break;
    case 1:
        console.log('Number 1');
        break;
}
// Number 1

var j = "1";
switch (j) {
    case "1":
        console.log('String 1');
        break;
    case 1:
        console.log('Number 1');
        break;
}
// String 1
```

The prompt function returns a string so either:

- Change your case statements to `case "1":`, `case "2":`
- Case the user input to a number using `i = Number(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Besides other answers, you can use the unary plus +. It actually does the same thing as Number(...), but is shorter.
In other words, the plus operator + applied to a single value, doesn’t do anything to numbers. But if the operand is not a number, the unary plus converts it into a number.

for instance:

```
let a = '2';
alert( a + 3); // 23
```

but

```
let a = '2';
alert( +a + 3); // 5
```

so add unary + before prompt in your code:

```
var i = +prompt("Type any number from where you want to start counting[Between 0 and 10]");
```